# Is the phrase 'being of a number' correct?

Tags: grammar

"Tribal population is of a considerable number in these two tahsils." Is this correct? I see many phrases like "It is of considerable importance ...", but does "being of a sizeable, considerable, etc. number" considers native English? For example, "The problems of our educational system is of a sizeable number". That said, I want to use it in academic or formal writings.

Comment: Yes. It is an example of a well-established idiom to say: "The problems of our educational system ARE of a sizeable number". The same idiom would include such things as "It was a building of a substantial size", "The student is a young man of an impressive intellect" etc.

Answer (score 1):

Population is a number, so it is the population which is large. I suggest

> The tribal population of these two tahsils is considerable.

Or

> There is a considerable tribal population in these two tahsils.

The **second** sentence

> The problems of our educational system is of a sizeable number

is clumsy, and could be better as

> There are many problems in our educational system

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a better way to describe the population would be "size". Therefore:

> "Tribal population is of considerable size".

For the other sentence I would suggest:

> "The problems of our educational system are numerous"

going back to your question, about it being correct, you are using the noun correctly, but I would not say it is common practice for native English speakers to use it this way.